# Error con Shared Preferences en Flutter

Tags: flutter, windows

Estoy creando una app con la cual deseo guardar datos persistentes con shared preferences el main.dart esta de esta manera:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:atm_app/screens/screen.dart';
import 'package:atm_app/share_preferences/preferences_global.dart';
import 'package:atm_app/providers/provider.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await PreferencesApp.init();
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => ThemeProvider(isDarkmode: PreferencesApp.isDarkmode)), //Aqui lo importe
    ],
    child: const MyApp(),
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'ATM APP',
      initialRoute: HomeScreen2.routerName,
      routes: {
        HomeScreen.routerName: (_) => const HomeScreen(),
        //Demas codigo
      },
      theme: Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).currentTheme,
    );
  }
}
```

Y en su construcción  esta de esta manera:

```
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class PreferencesApp {
  static late SharedPreferences _prefs;

  static bool _isDarkmode = false;
  

  static Future init() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  }

  static bool get isDarkmode {
    return _prefs.getBool('isDarkmode') ?? _isDarkmode;
  }

  static set isDarkmode(bool value) {
    _isDarkmode = value;
    _prefs.setBool('isDarkmode', value);
  }

  
}
```

A lo cual en otras ocasiones no me ha generado ningún conflicto, lo compilo sin problema en

1. Android
2. Web

Pero al intentar compilarlo para Windows me da el error

[image: Error inicial]

Específicamente en el bloque de código

```
static Future init() async {
    _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
}
```

¿Que esta mal? ocupo la ultima versión